# INSERT with a COUNT on the same table, in a single query?

Tags: mysql, count, insert

I'm trying to get the number of rows in a table, and then insert that number into that same table, all with a single query. I looked at subquery and it **throws error** since I'm doing it on the **same table**.

Then I looked at **variables** and it works but mySQL still throws an error about empty result.

```
SET @nums := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myitems);
INSERT INTO myitems ( `label`, `counted`) VALUES ('blah', @nums);
```

Can I trust this will be robust? I'm not super expert on SQL statements.

PS: I know about `AUTO_INCREMENT` which you might think should be utilized here. I simplified my situation to keep the question esy to digest (and hopefully answer).

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)?

```
INSERT INTO myitems( `label`, `counted`)
SELECT 'blah', COUNT(*) FROM myitems;
```

I don't know why you would do this but it does answer your question

Comment: I must not be very good at explaining my question -  I want to insert the number of current rows in the table as a record in that table.

Comment: And that's what this code does. If you ran it, as-is, you would get a row with `blah` and the count of records in the table at that time.